# How to use SELECT with LIMIT in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to run the query using PDO to get a few rows in descending order.

I am my using MySQL 5.7.27 and PHP 7.2.

```
$con = new PDO(".....");
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `tab` ORDER BY DESC LIMIT :start, :limit";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `tab` ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 0, 2";

$stmt = $con->preapre($sql1);
$stmt->execute(['start'=>0, 'limit'=>2]);
$array = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($array as $rows) {
     //Getting empty here
}
```

***sql1*** doesn't give me any row. However, ***sql2*** gives me rows. I would like to get rows with ***sql1***. What are the mistakes here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use parameters for the values in a `LIMIT` range in MySQL.  One workaround might be to use row number, and then restrict to a range of values:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
        @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
    FROM tab t,
       (SELECT @rn := 0) r
) t
WHERE rn BETWEEN :start AND :end;
```

For example, if you wanted the 4th and 5th records, you would use:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->execute(['start'=>4, 
'end'=>5]);
$array = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

LIMIT is expecting the offset and count to be integers. The problem you have is that `:start` and `:limit` are being typecast as strings.

One simple solution would be to cast your value as an integer first.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':start', (int) 0, PDO::PARAM_INT); // make sure to keep (int) when passing in a variable.
$stmt->bindValue(':limit', (int) 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```